# Hamcrest assertion of boolean fields with an "is" prefix getter method

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

We would like to assert that a list of custom objects contains an object with some of its fields having certain values, with a series of assertions like this

```
assertThat(customObjectList, hasItem(hasProperty("someField", equalTo(someValue))));
```

However the custom object has also boolean type fields, where the getter method has an "is" prefix instead of "get", and there the assertion seems to fail with

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: a collection containing hasProperty("booleanField", <true>) but: property "booleanField" is not readable
```

Is there an out-of-the-box solution to overcome this, or it should be handled with some kind of custom matcher?

Comment: This should work with primitive `boolean`s. Are you maybe talking about `Boolean` Objects?

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the fields are Boolean type. The class in question is actually JPA/Hibernate entity with all of its field types being objects and not primitives. We can not modify the class itself and have to find some solution to circumvent it in the tests

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hamcrest uses internally the `java.beans.PropertyDescriptor` that implements the standard `JavaBean` behaviour, allowing the `is` just for the boolean primitive types.

I'm afraid you will have to create your own `Matcher` (something like hasGetterValue)

Answer (score 1):

FYI: one can use Hamcrest extension [shazamcrest](https://github.com/shazam/shazamcrest) and it's `sameBeanAs` (`DiagnosingCustomisableMatcher`) which works perfectly fine even for `Boolean` types ;)