# Hamcrest matcher for list of complex objects with each containing a list of complex objects

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Sorry for the long title, but my problem is as follows;

I have these classes;

```
public class A {
    int a1;
    int a2;
    List<B> listOfB;
}
```

and

```
public class B {
    int b1;
    int b2;
    List<C> listOfC;
}
```

and

```
public class C {
    int c1;
    int c2;
}
```

If it were only for `B` to assert the list of `C` it has, I would use the following custom matcher;
`Matcher<Iterable<C>> cMatcher = Matchers.hasItems(allOf(hasProperty("c1", equalTo(c1)), hasProperty("c2", equalTo(c2))))`

But how can I do the assertion from `A`? I want to use this `C` list matcher in a larger scope matcher that does the following;

`Matchers.hasItems(allOf(hasProperty("b1", equalTo(b1)), hasProperty("b2", equalTo(b2)), hasProperty("listOfC", cMatcher)))`

So in a way I wish to match a `B` in `listOfB` where has given `b1`, and `b2` values, together with its `listOfC` containing a specific `C` with values `c1` and `c2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but the code I gave at the end was correct. There were some problems with the matcher constraints of the inner list `C`.

So to match a list in a list;

`Matcher<Iterable<C>> cMatcher = Matchers.hasItems(allOf(hasProperty("c1", equalTo(c1)), hasProperty("c2", equalTo(c2))))`

Then use this in the higher scope matcher;

`Matchers.hasItems(allOf(hasProperty("b1", equalTo(b1)), hasProperty("b2", equalTo(b2)), hasProperty("listOfC", cMatcher)))`

will match for the case I have described in my question.

The problem I have encountered is a field in my `C` class, which has type of `Boolean`, somehow `hasProperty("boolField", true)` does not match, saying `property "boolField" is not readable`. Probably due to the getter method of Boolean hasn't got a `get` prefix, [in this question, it says primitive boolean works, while Boolean object fails in this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32987750/hamcrest-assertion-of-boolean-fields-with-an-is-prefix-getter-method)

Answer (score 0):

Whilst you *could* create a composite Hamcrest matcher, the difficulties you are facing outline a drawback in your testing approach.

The [Law of Demeter](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) suggests that you bound the testing to each class and not beyond.

That `A` has a correct list of `B` is fine, but how those `C`s behave is entirely up to `B` and would belong in *its* tests.

Comment: I agree, but the classes I am talking about is in the response object of the main method of the class that I am actually testing. The structure of these `A`, `B`, and `C` classes are out of my reach.

Answer (score 0):

hasItems does partial match. Use containsInAnyOrder for exact match.

http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html